# Calculate total size of all un-deletable files (including files in subdirectories)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, find

I have a somewhat weird problem, where there's a shared storage on a server with hundreds of users. I want to identify all the files that would not be deletable by my user (**if** I tried to run an auto-delete script).

For all these identified files, I need the long-listing format (ie: full path, owner, last modified, size). My current understanding is this would be all the files whose immediate parent directories are non-writable by me, please correct me if this approach is wrong.

After identifying these files, I also need to get the total size they're occupying. Although, this step can also be done by using a simple python script too add all the sizes, but I'm still looking if there's a better way to do it.

Here's my current approach:

```sh
find /downloads/ -type d ! -writable -print0 |
xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -I{.} ls -l {.} > myfile.txt
```

- Find all directories (recursively) that are non-writable by my user
- Find all the immediate children of each of these directories, and filter out only the files.
- Get a long-listing for each of these identified files and store results in a .txt file
- Read this .txt file with python and add all the individual sizes (in bytes) to get the total size. Divide by (1024*1024*1024) to get size in GB. (python script below:)

```py
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    total_size = 0
    for line in f:
        try:
            data = line.split()
            if len(data) > 5:
                total_size += int(data[4]) # "4" is the index of the size column
        except:
            pass
print("Total Size:", str(round(total_size/(1024*1024*1024), 2)), "GB")
```

---

The problem I'm facing with this approach is that the final size I'm getting is the total size of the entire volume.

> My answer = **1400.02GB** (as reported by following the steps above)
> The total size of the entire shared space = **1400.02GB**
> Actual occupied space on the shared server = **800GB**
> Expected answer should be **<800GB**

So you see the problem is that my answer is equal to the total size of the entire server space, including the space that's not even occupied.

---

This mismatch between my answer (1400.02GB) and the expected answer (<800GB) ALSO makes me question the correctness of the files that have been identified.

Could someone please suggest a better way to do this, or point out the problem in my approach so that I can fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your find line looks pretty ok'ish to me. Do you only encounter that problem on that remote share? Have you checked (some) of the lines in myfile.txt for suspicious matches (counting the lines could also give a first idea)? Could you post your Python script, too?

Comment: A grand total could be obtained with `find . -type d -writable -print0 | xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | du -csh --files0-from=-
`

Comment: @HarshitJindal : I would not use `ls` here at all. Instead I would feed the name of the files into Python and do the size calculation directly from within Python. I think this will make it easier to detect any discrepancy.

Comment: @senatoresconscripti I've provided the python file, thank you :)

Comment: @LMC Thank you sooo much, it worked. I finally got an answer 471GB which makes sense since it's about half of the total occupied volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two reasons why just adding bytes reported by `ls` to calculate disk usage has to be considered naive:

1. You're double counting hardlinked files, even though a hardlink is just a directory entry taking basically no extra disk space.
2. If you want to find out the actual disk usage ("get the total size they're occupying") you have to consider the block size. E.g. a directory with 1000 1-byte files can take much more space than a directory with one 1MB file

So the right tool for the job is `du`. But in order for `du` to be able to do his job correctly and not double counting hardlinks you've to give it all files to check at once. Luckily the GNU version of `du` has the `--files0-from` option for that, e.g. you can use

```
find . -type d ! -writable -print0 |
du -ch -d 1 --files0-from=- |
tail -n 1
```

This also avoids the `xargs` which can be very slow due to the `-I` option which means you're doing a `find` invocation for each argument.

Comment: There's a slight difference of 10GB between your command and @LMC's command `find . -type d -writable -print0 | xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | du -csh --files0-from=-`, although yours took significantly less time to run

Comment: `-d N` does **not** exclude the subdirectories from the total. It just prevents printing the individual size for subdirectories deeper than N levels (`-d 0` is equivalent to `-s`/`--summarize`). ¶ That you only got a *small* difference means your unwritable directories do not contain any large subdirectories.

Comment: At least for GNU `du`, the only option to exclude the subdirectories from the total is `--exclude=PATTERN` or `-X`/`-exclude-from=FILE`. But those are rather useless for this task in case of directory structures like `/1-unwriteable/2-writeable/3-unwriteable`.

Comment: @HarshitJindal, @Socowi: Yes I wasn't sure if `-d 1` (or `-d 0`) does the right thing. Maybe you can try the `-S`/`--separate-dirs` option which is documented as `for directories do not include size of subdirectories` to see if that works as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your command gave such a wrong number, but here is another one you could try.

Note that *"total size they're occupying"* can differ a lot from the sum of sizes printed by `ls` due to things like file system blocks, hardlinks, and sparse files. So we use `du` instead of `ls` to get the sizes.

The following command is basically [LMC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154529/calculate-total-size-of-all-un-deletable-files-including-files-in-subdirectorie/69156064#comment122228312_69154529), but incorporates `ls` into the same search and uses `-exec +` instead of `xargs -I`, which should drastically speed up the command, as you run the second `find` only a handful of times instead of once for each directory.

```
#! /bin/bash

longlist() {
  ls -l "$@" >> "$longlistfile"
}
filesonly() {
  find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'longlist "$@"' . {} + -print0
}
export -f longlist filesonly
export longlistfile=myfile.txt

rm -f "$longlistfile"
find . -type d \! -writable -exec bash -c 'filesonly "$@"' . {} + |
du -ch --files0-from=- | tail -n1
```